Modify OuterXml of a given node to keep it in file, but render node useless
I'm working on modifying xml files from an existing system using PowerShell.  Our system supports using multiple nodes in one body, and depending on what the OuterXML is set as, it will bypass that value and use the other node of similar value (I suppose this may be true of all XML files but I do not want to make poor Assumptions).
Consider this XML file example.  The way to modify our files to stop the use of the specific node is to prepend the node's OuterXml with an x:
<Configuration>
  <MainBlock>
    <Object NO="01" REVISION="255">
       <CODE TRANSPARENT="TRUE" />
    </Object>
    <Object NO="02" REVISION="255">
       <CODE TRANSPARENT="TRUE" />
    </Object>
    <Object NO="03" REVISION="255">
       <CODE TRANSPARENT="TRUE" />
    </Object>
    <Object NO="04" REVISION="255">
       <CODE TRANSPARENT="TRUE" />
    </Object>
    <!--Note - this line is the line I wish to modify so it is no longer in use.  The example below was edited manually-->
    <xObject NO="05" REVISION="255">
       <CODE TRANSPARENT="TRUE" />
    </xObject>
    <!--By prepending the "OuterXML" of the node above to "xObject" instead of "Object" I can keep the original values there, but use the "Object" below with a different code - this is an extremely simplified version of this concept.-->
    <Object NO="05" REVISION="255">
       <CODE TRANSPARENT="FALSE" />
    </Object>
  </MainBlock>
</Configuration>

The problem I'm having specifically is modifying the OuterXml of a given node, since OuterXml is a read-only attribute . . .  When I see the nodes using $nodes = $Xml.SelectNodes to gather the Objects, I return a count of 5 (as expected with this solution), but how on earth do I modify the OuterXml of the the xObject node to read as Object and the Object Node below it to read as xObject?  Here's my attempt:
  $Xml=[XML] (Get-Content -Path C:\FooBar.xml)
  
  $nodes=$Xml.SelectNodes("//Configuration/MainBlock/Object")
  $node = $nodes.Item(4).OuterXml #<< Here I can set the $node value as a STRING but not an actual XML element, but the $node element DOES contain the contents of the OuterXml Content.
  $nodes.Item(4) = $node #This does not error out but it also does NOTHING to the existing XML content
  
  $Xml.Save("C:\FooBar.xml")

Understand - there about 25 different attributes / values for each Object node within the actual XML structure I'm dealing with - this sample is just to illustrate the concept quickly/simply.  While in the example above, I could easily just modify the Transparent value to "True" - that's not going feasible for me to accomplish on our files.
I know I can use the -replace command to replace the "Object" with "xObject" using PowerShell from a purely "Find and Replace" perspective, but I'm trying to use PowerShell's XML functions to their best potential.
  #While this works, it's kludgy and isn't fool proof.
  $XmlFile=(Get-Content -Path C:\FooBar.xml)
  $TextToChange=$XmlFile -replace 'xObject','fooObject'; -replace 'Object NO=\"5','xObject NO=\"5'; -replace 'fooObject','Object'
  Set-Content -Path C:\FooBar.xml -Value $TextToChange


It is better to use XSLT for such tasks, and just call that XSLT from the PowerShell

Thanks @YitzhakKhabinsky, but with the system I'm operating within, I do not have the template necessary to use XSLT and it will not be released to me.  The approach I'm required to take will need to utilize straight XML modification of some kind.



You're looking for a way to directly rename an XML element, but this is not supported in the [xml] (System.Xml.XmlDocument)-related APIs - and, if I were to guess, also not in most, if not all, other XML APIs.

That $nodes.Item(4) = $node is a quiet no-op rather than an error (which it should be, because .Item() is a method here, so it cannot be assigned to) is an unfortunate PowerShell bug:

See GitHub issue #24074.




Workarounds:

If you don't mind working with different APIs, from the System.Xml.Linq namespace, see jdweng's answer.

Note:

The System.Xml.Linq.XDocument-focused APIs are the modern successor to the System.Xml.XmlDocument ([xml]) APIs and are unquestionably easier to work with in C# and, for structural DOM manipulations - such as in this case - possibly also in PowerShell. However, unlike for [xml] , PowerShell offers no syntactic sugar for System.Xml.Linq.XDocument, so learning the specifics of the latter APIs is a must.

By contrast, in PowerShell, reading an XML DOM as well as making non-structural modifications is usually easier, due to PowerShell's close integration with the [xml] APIs that allows treating an XML DOM like an object graph, with elements and attributes accessible as properties (see this answer for background information). In simple cases, no API-specific knowledge is required, allowing for a unified OOP approach.





A solution based on the [xml] APIs you're using is possible too:

As implied by the notes above, structural modification is a bit more cumbersome, and to emulate renaming you have to take the following steps:

Create a new element with the desired new name.
Move the original element's attributes and child elements to the new element.
Insert the new element after the original one.
Remove the original element.


Aside from the unavoidable use of the [xml]-related methods for the above, the rest of the code takes advantage of the aforementioned OOP-style PowerShell integration, aka PowerShell's adaptation of the [xml] DOM.




# Load the XML file into an [xml] (System.Xml.XmlDocument) DOM.
# Note: 
#  * The form below is more robust than [xml] (Get-Content -Path C:\FooBar.xml)
#  * Be sure to use a *full* file path in .NET methods, because .NET's working
#    dir. usually differs from PowerShell's; use Convert-Path with a relative
#    path to get a full one, e.g., Convert-Path FooBar.xml
$fullFilePath = 'C:\FooBar.xml'
($xml = [xml]::new()).Load($fullFilePath)

# Get the target elements by their 'NO' attribute value, 
# both the <xObject> and the <Object> element.
[array] $targetElements = 
  $xml.Configuration.MainBlock.ChildNodes |
  Where-Object NO -EQ '05'

if ($targetElements.Count -eq 0) { throw "No matching element(s) found." }

# Determine the parent element.
$parentElement = $targetElements[0].ParentNode

# Construct the replacement elements.
$replacementElements = 
  $targetElements |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Change 'xObject' to 'Object' and vice versa.
    $newName = if ($_.Name -clike 'x*') { $_.Name.Substring(1) } else { 'x' + $_.Name }
    $replacementElement = $xml.CreateElement($newName, $_.NamespaceURI)
    # Move all attributes from the target node to the replacement...
    $null = foreach ($a in @($_.Attributes)) { $replacementElement.Attributes.Append($a) }
    # ... and all child elements.
    $null = foreach ($e in @($_.ChildNodes)) { $replacementElement.AppendChild($e) }
    # Output the newly constructed replacement element.
    $replacementElement
  } 

# Now insert the replacement elements, each right after its original.
$i = 0
$null = 
  $replacementElements | ForEach-Object { 
    $parentElement.InsertAfter($_, $targetElements[$i++])
  }
# ... and remove the original ones.
$null = $targetElements | ForEach-Object { $parentElement.RemoveChild($_) }

# Save back to the input file.
$xml.Save($fullFilePath)


Your solution solves the question I had commented on jdweng's answer, however, unlike jdweng's answer, where it put the targeted node in the same order, your option puts the targeted node at the TOP of the Mainblock instead of in line.  I tried to change the order as your comments mentioned by uncommenting $replacementElements | ForEach-Object { $parentElement.InsertAfter($_, $targetElements[-1]) } and commented out the next 2 lines but it put the updated object at the top again, without the modified value.  Reading again - I think I need to substitute the line.  Trying this now.

@k1dfr0std, as far as I can tell, the node order is preserved; however, (a) there was a bug in case only one target node was found (since fixed with an [array] type constraint), and (b) the order preservation is based on the assumption that the <Object> and <xObject> elements are adjacent; the code uses whichever of the two comes last as the insertion point for the replacements.

YEP - that's what I just discovered.  If I also wanted to adapt this code to also disable (change Object to xObject) and keep the order, would I need to change the $insertAfterElement = $argetElements[-1] line to whatever the $parentElement index of the representative object is to insert in place while removing the original element?

I figured it out!  IF there is only ONE Object of the same "NO" - this is solved by modifying the $parentElement = $targetElements[0].ParentNode to $parentElement = $targetElements.ParentNode and then indeed by modifying $insertAfterElement = $targetElements[-1] line to $insertAfterElement = $targetElements and removing the arrays entirely.  I think this should be simple enough to mock up into an if condition - I'll attempt this next.

@k1dfr0std, the [array] type constraint obviates the need to distinguish between finding only one vs. two elements. Please see my updated insertion code, which I believe now works like you want.

Using your updated insertion code, I get a cannot call method on null-valued expression error on both the insertion and the removal lines, whereas, if I modify it to include If ($targetElements.Count -gt 1) towards the beginning, and specify [0].ParentNode vs .ParentNode for the parent, and set a boolean var to reference later for isArray - I can then check that condition for isArray and at the insertion point, change $insertAfterElement = . . . to either be [-1] specific, or just the singular $targetElement variant

@k1dfr0std if  you want to handle the case when  no matching elements, use if ($targetElements.Count -eq 0) { throw "No matching element(s) found." } right after setting $targetElements (answer updated). Beyond that, the code in the answer requires no special handling to distinguish between the case of finding one or two matching elements (or even more than that, which would each be subject to turning <xSomeName> into <SomeName> and vice versa).

Oh my goodness. . . . I'm so blind.  I put the [array] type constraint on the $parentNode line!  DUH!  You're absolutely correct - This indeed solved it.  I put the [array] constraint as you mentioned on the $targetElements line and voila - worked like a charm.

Glad to hear we got to the bottom of it, @k1dfr0std.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Use Xml Linq with Powershell
using assembly System.Xml
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
$mainBlock = $doc.Descendants('MainBlock').Foreach([System.Xml.Linq.XElement])[0]
$objects = $mainBlock.Elements().Foreach([System.Xml.Linq.XElement])
$tags = [Linq.Enumerable]::Select($objects, [Func[object,string]] { param($x) $x.Name.LocalName }) | foreach { $_ }

$index = $tags.IndexOf('xObject')

$xObject = $objects[$index]
$xObject.ReplaceWith([System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new('Object', @($xObject.Attributes(), $xObject.Elements())))

$xObject = $objects[$index + 1]
$xObject.ReplaceWith([System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new('xObject', @($xObject.Attributes(), $xObject.Elements())))

$doc


This works well for the starter needs - I was hoping to take this and expand this thought into dynamically telling the system to disable an object when another xobject does not exist.  If every one of these has the NO="##" format - how do I get that level of detail using the Linq options?  I know that with the other XML method, I can choose the path by stating something like //object[@NO='05' and modifying that one - is it still possible using this Linq style of manipulation?

Currently, the $x.Name.LocalName only produces the main name of it, but I cannot see directly what number is associated with that node and the number of objects held in this file varies.  For example - if I write-host the contents of the |Foreach { $_ }, I see 5 Objectswith thexObject2nd to last (as expected) - but what if I also need to disableObjectNO 2?  Without sifting through the indexes - is it possible to hook onto the verbiage stating explicitlyNO="02"` ?  This is a fantastic start nonetheless and works as long as there's always a previously disabled object.

At some point I may need to brush up on this different API - it handles differently and I'm just trying to get a project off the ground - thank you for these examples - It does indeed solve the original problem, but the need to also detect singular entries and either remove them or enable them could not be solved by this method alone, and I couldn't understand it well enough without further research.  Good stuff nonetheless

You can get attribute values with : $xObject.Attribute('NO').Value

You can use PS methods or Linq methods to search.  $objects.Elements() | Where-Object $_.Attribute('NO').Value -eq '02')  or Linq method : [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($objects, [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) [string]$x.Attribute('NO').Value -eq '02'})

PS is written in Microsoft Net/Core Library.  The code I posed is from XDocument which is the enhanced XML Linq library.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/basic-queries-linq-to-xml  I often test code in Visual Studio using c# and then convert to PS.

Reconsider XSLT as suggested above in comments where you supply the template. Because XSLT is XML, read and parse the stylesheet similar to input XML. Going this route, you avoid forEach loops and if logic in PS. Plus, XSLT as an industry language is portable and runnable outside of PowerShell (Perl, Python, Java, Saxon, Xalan, etc.) using same XML input.
Specifically, below XSLT uses the Identity Transform template to copy document as is and then renames the <Object> node to <xObject> that contains the attribute NO = '05'. Potentially, '05' can be parameterized were PowerShell passes a literal to stylesheet. (Because XSLT 1.0 disallows using parameters in template match, a more verbose conditional handling is run).
XSLT (save as .xsl file)
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="no_param"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Object">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="@NO=$no_param">
       <xObject>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       </xObject>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <Object>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       </Object>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

For XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processors use this shorter second template:
<xsl:template match="Object[@NO=$no_param]">
  <xObject>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xObject>
</xsl:template>

PowerShell
$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
$argList = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList
$argList.AddParam("no_param", "", "05")

$xslt.Load("C:\Path\To\Style.xsl")
$xslt.Transform("C:\Path\To\Input.xml", $argList, "C:\Path\To\Output.xml");

